# How to make byte my default music player?

Tags: settings, default

So I like *Byte music player* more than the default music app in elementary OS, I've installed and used *Byte* but in the settings in default applications it doesn't appear in the context menu of music players, Any idea of how can I make it appear in there?

Answer (score 1):

To appear in Music Player dropdown in 'Default Applications' list, your app's `.desktop` file (the one in `/usr/share/applications`) should contain `Categories=Audio;Music;Player;` line. If it doesn't contain this line, try adding it manually and see if the app will appear in the `Music Player` dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a `.desktop` launcher in `/usr/share/applications` and has `%F` after the exec command like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit %F
```

You should be able to choose it as a default application in the file manager, not sure about the default applications part, it should be there too but I'm not sure.

Edited: Had the wrong character to add.

Comment: Mmm no i revised the file and it doesn't have tan %U, so i can't chose it to play music files as default app, also that file doesn't let me modify anything i think because of root permissions or something

Comment: Sorry got that a bit wrong it's a %F you want to add to the exec command. You can copy the .desktop file to /home/username/.local/applications and add the %F there with normal permissions. Or use sudo and add it in the original local using "sudo nano /usr/share/applications/app_name.desktop".